# Stripe on iOS and saving card details

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I need to implement "Save card" and "Delete card" features in my iOS app.
From Stripe documentations I found that we can create a customerId on our backend and link it to our internal userId.

But we need part of card details to display it to user. E.g.

`Visa card xxxx xxxx xxxx 8153`

1. Is it ok to store this data on backend and iOS app? I'm talking about card type and last 4 digits.
2. Should we create new customerId in Stripe if we want to store more than one card per customer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are certain details that are available when you store a card; you don't need to store them separately. "Last 4" and type are some of the fields available from the API; check out the Stripe docs for cards for more. https://stripe.com/docs/api#cards
2. No, you don't need to create a new customer (and in fact, would probably be a bad thing for keeping everything cleanly coordinated). Store additional cards on the same customer.